# scrapy splash to solve recaptcha

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy+splash to web scrape,I have a "anti recaptcha" third party service that can solve the recaptcha, the way the recaptcha solver works is that  they an array of what I should click on (correct images). How can I click on the pictures using scrapy+splash ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn [Splash scripting](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-tutorial.html#scripting-tutorial).